# Не получается создать обертку (Wrapper) без дэфолтного конструктора

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Пытаюсь создать класс обертку и IDEA подсказывает, что я обяза создать добавить дэфолтный конструктор без аргументов в класс родитель. Соответственно вопрос, а что создать класс обертку без дэфолтного конструктора в классе родителе нельзя? Вот код:

Класс родитель:

```
public class Tank implements Serializable{
    String name;

    public Tank(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(name != null){
            return this.name + "\n";
        }else {
            return "Имя не указано";
        }
    }
}
```

Класс обертка:

```
public class TankWrapper extends Tank {
    Tank original;

    public TankWrapper(Tank original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Мое имя: " + original.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут дело в том, что вам надо в конструкторах классов-наследников вызывать один из конструкторов класса предка. Т.к. вы этого не делаете, то IDE предполагает что вы имеете в виду дефолтный конструктор. А его у вас нет, т.к. в супер классе есть недефолтный конструктор.

Думаю, вам надо просто вызвать конструктор предка в наследнике как-то так:

```
public class TankWrapper extends Tank {
    Tank original;

    public TankWrapper(Tank original) {
        super(original.toString());
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Мое имя: " + original.toString();
    }
}
```